# Modify list-column by reference in nested data.table

Tags: r, data.table

When using a list column of data.tables in a nested data.table it is easy to apply a function over the column. Example:

```
dt<- data.table(mtcars)[, list(dt.mtcars = list(.SD)), by = gear]
```

We can use:

```
dt[ ,list(length = nrow(dt.mtcars[[1]])), by = gear]

dt[ ,list(length = nrow(dt.mtcars[[1]])), by = gear]

   gear length
1:    4     12
2:    3     15
3:    5      5
```

or

```
dt[, list( length = lapply(dt.mtcars, nrow)), by = gear]

  gear length
1:    4     12
2:    3     15
3:    5      5
```

I would like to do the same process and apply a modification by reference using the operator `:=` to each data.table of the column.

Example:

```
modify_by_ref<- function(d){

  d[, max_hp:= max(hp)]


}

dt[, modify_by_ref(dt.mtcars[[1]]), by  = gear]
```

That returns the error:

```
 Error in `[.data.table`(d, , `:=`(max_hp, max(hp))) : 
  .SD is locked. Using := in .SD's j is reserved for possible future use; a tortuously flexible way to modify by group. Use := in j directly to modify by group by reference.
```

Using the tip in the error message do not works in any way for me, it seems to be targeting another case but maybe I am missing something. Is there any recommended way or flexible workaround to modify list columns by refence?

Comment: As I understand the error message, it's telling that exactly what you are trying to do is not possible (yet). Instead you have to use `:=` directly in your j-expression

Comment: The problem with using `:=` directly in the j-expression is that is possible only if the data.table is unnested first.

Comment: This is generally not advisable. Stack your tables into one and do `by=` operations, which are optimized for `max` and other common summary functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in following two steps or in Single Step:

The given table is:

```
dt<- data.table(mtcars)[, list(dt.mtcars = list(.SD)), by = gear]
```

Step 1 - Let's add list of column `hp` vectors in each row of `dt`

```
dt[, hp_vector := .(list(dt.mtcars[[1]][, hp])), by = list(gear)]
```

Step 2 - Now calculate the max of `hp`

```
dt[, max_hp := max(hp_vector[[1]]), by = list(gear)]
```

The given table is:

```
dt<- data.table(mtcars)[, list(dt.mtcars = list(.SD)), by = gear]
```

Single Step - Single step is actually the combination of both of the above steps:

```
dt[, max_hp := .(list(max(dt.mtcars[[1]][, hp])[[1]])), by = list(gear)]
```

If we wish to populate values within nested table by Reference then the following link talks about how to do it, just that we need to ignore a warning message. I will be happy if anyone can point me how to fix the warning message or is there any pitfall. For more detail please refer the link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306010/how-can-i-do-fast-advance-data-manipulation-in-nested-data-table-data-table-wi/48412406#48412406
```

Taking inspiration from the same i am going to show how to do it here for the given data set.

Let's first clean everything:

```
rm(list = ls())
```

Let's re-define the given table in different way:

```
dt<- data.table(mtcars)[, list(dt.mtcars = list(data.table(.SD))), by = list(gear)]
```

Note that i have defined the table slightly different. I have used `data.table` in addition to list in the above definition.

Next, populate the max by reference within nested table:

```
dt[, dt.mtcars := .(list(dt.mtcars[[1]][, max_hp := max(hp)])), by = list(gear)]
```

And, what good one can expect, we can perform manipulation within nested table:

```
dt[, dt.mtcars := .(list(dt.mtcars[[1]][, weighted_hp_carb := max_hp*carb])), by = list(gear)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed tutorial, but your solution doesn't actually address the question. It creates a new column in dt, while the desired output would be a new column *inside* each nested data.table. ( that, as commented by other users, is not possible yet.)

Comment: To see the difference, consider the case where the function is actually an injection and not a summary( ex: new_hp = hp + 1).

Comment: Actually, that's why i pointed to refer the link for more detail. Anyways, here is how we can add max_hp in nested table (I have updated my answer). Also, we can do manipulations. Let me know if you could figure out any pitfalls of using it.

Comment: @Nicolas Pinto - any comment??

Comment: Great, with the editions your answers is the best solution I have seen so far. I would appreciate if you edit again just to warn that the first suggestion do not solve the problem. I actually think that omitting it and going directly to the solution would be a better approach, but that is your choice. Thanks!