# How can i do FAST/ADVANCE data manipulation in nested data.table - data.table within data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table named `route_data` in R. I need to create a nested data.table `leg_data` to each row of `route_data` with information extracted from each row of `route_data`

```
route_data <- data.table(route = c("Seattle>NewDelhi>Patna>Motihari", "Seattle>NewDelhi>Motihari","Seattle>Hyderabad>NewDelhi>Patna>Motihari"),
                         travel_type = c("business_meeting", "casual_trip","office_meeting"), 
                         leg1_time_hr = c(18.0,18.0,18.0),
                         leg2_time_hr = c(2,18,2.25),
                         leg3_time_hr = c(4.0,NA,1.75),
                         leg4_time_hr = c(NA,NA,4.0))
```

`route_data`

```
             route                           travel_type          leg1_time_hr  leg2_time_hr leg3_time_hr leg4_time_hr
1:           Seattle>NewDelhi>Patna>Motihari business_meeting           18         2.00         4.00           NA
2:                 Seattle>NewDelhi>Motihari      casual_trip           18        18.00           NA           NA
3: Seattle>Hyderabad>NewDelhi>Patna>Motihari   office_meeting           18         2.25         1.75            4
```

I need to create a nested `leg_data` in `route_data`for example in the first row that should look like this:

```
example_nested_data <- data.table(leg = c("Seattle>Hyderabad", "Hyderabad>NewDelhi","NewDelhi>Patna","Patna>Motihari"),
                         leg_num = c(1,2,3,4), 
                         leg_transit_time_hr = c(18.0,2.25,1.75,4.0)
                         )
```

`example_nested_data` in row 1 of `route_data`

```
    leg                  leg_num           leg_transit_time_hr
1:  Seattle>Hyderabad       1               18.00
2: Hyderabad>NewDelhi       2                2.25
3:     NewDelhi>Patna       3                1.75
4:     Patna>Motihari       4                4.00
```

Similarly, in the second and third row of `route_data`

Comment: Please add more details as to how/what you have tried, and what results you got.

Comment: Yes. I added it now. It works fine except for warning message that I am unable to fix... Could you please suggest. In general your comment is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try answering it myself. I am seeing Warning message in a hope to understand it better for any limitations. However, for me it works fine (ignoring the warning message).

On a side note, data.table breaks all the limitation of R that stops it to do Big Data processing, and lest i forget my own research would like it to be documented.

Meanwhile let us create a function that breaks up the route in legs:

```
construct.legs <- function(ro) {
      node_vector <- unlist(strsplit(ro, ">"))
      d_nodes <- node_vector[!node_vector %in% node_vector[1]]
      o_nodes <- node_vector[!node_vector %in% node_vector[length(node_vector)]]
      legs <- paste(o_nodes,d_nodes, sep = ">")
    }
```

Now create nested `leg_table` for each route containing legs of the route. Of course using the function `construct.legs` that was defined above:

```
route_data[, leg_data := .(list(data.table(leg = construct.legs(route)))), by = list(row.names(route_data))]
```

How does our `route_data` look like now?

```
                                       route      travel_type leg1_time_hr leg2_time_hr leg3_time_hr leg4_time_hr     leg_data
1:           Seattle>NewDelhi>Patna>Motihari business_meeting           18         2.00         4.00           NA <data.table>
2:                 Seattle>NewDelhi>Motihari      casual_trip           18        18.00           NA           NA <data.table>
3: Seattle>Hyderabad>NewDelhi>Patna>Motihari   office_meeting           18         2.25         1.75            4 <data.table>
```

Let's take a look what is inside if the nested data.table in 3rd row of `route_data`

```
route_data$leg_data[3]  #Access the leg_table like we do in data.frame. But this returns leg_data as a list
route_data$leg_data[[3]]  #This returns leg_data as a data.table
route_data[3, leg_data] #Access the leg_table like we do in data.table. This returns leg_data as a list
route_data[3, leg_data[[1]]] #This returns leg_data as a data.table
```

data.table stored in the 3rd row of `route_data`

```
                  leg
1:  Seattle>Hyderabad
2: Hyderabad>NewDelhi
3:     NewDelhi>Patna
4:     Patna>Motihari
```

Let me add row number in `route_data` tha i will use later in populating transit time within nested table `leg_data`

```
route_data[, route_num := seq_len(.N)]
```

Similarly add row number in nested table `leg_Table`

```
route_data[, leg_data := .(list(leg_data[[1]][, leg_num := seq_len(.N)])), by = list(row.names(route_data))]
```

You see a Warning message that says there was invalid internal self reference that has been fixed by shallow copying. So, i am going to ignore this as of now. I would need help here from someone who can help me understand if it breaks anything. Anyway, lets proceed.

Why do we have `[[1]]`? This is to ensure that sub_table values are returned as data.table, not as list. Try running `route_data[3, leg_data[[1]]]` and `route_data[3, leg_data]` to see the difference.

Now finally add the transit time in nested `leg_data` from `route_data`

```
route_data[, leg_data := .(list(leg_data[[1]][, leg_transit_time_hr := sapply(leg_num, function(x) {route_data[[route_num, 2+x, with = FALSE]]})])), by = list(row.names(route_data))]
```

What did we do here?

We just looped in row number `leg_num` of `leg_data` via sapply by passing it as vector and utilized the row number `route_num` of `route_data` to identify right column of transit time to extract from the `route_data`.

Why did we place double `[[]]` on the `[[route_num, 2+x, with = FALSE]]`?

Double braces ensure it returns value as vector not as data.table

And, finally, let's take a look into the nested data.table `leg_data` of 3rd row of `route_data`

```
route_data[3, leg_data[[1]]]
        leg             leg_num       leg_transit_time_hr
1:  Seattle>Hyderabad       1               18.00
2: Hyderabad>NewDelhi       2                2.25
3:     NewDelhi>Patna       3                1.75
4:     Patna>Motihari       4                4.00
```

Let's see how 2nd row nested table looks like:

```
         leg            leg_num       leg_transit_time_hr
1:  Seattle>NewDelhi       1                  18
2: NewDelhi>Motihari       2                  18
```

Comment: Also, refer my answer on the Question related to using References on the Nested data.table

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649403/modify-list-column-by-reference-in-nested-data-table/48430001#48430001